# cannot import name _parse_proxy (urllib2)

Tags: scrapy, urllib2

I was trying to use Scrapy with Python 2 and I got this error,

```
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 95, in crawl
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 77, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 102, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/__init__.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.middleware = DownloaderMiddlewareManager.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 58, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 34, in from_settings
    mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 44, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/httpproxy.py", line 4, in <module>
    from urllib2 import _parse_proxy
ImportError: cannot import name _parse_proxy
```

I have urllib2 installed

```
Name: urllib2
Version: 1498656401.94
Summary: Checking out the typosquatting state of PyPi
Home-page: https://github.com/benjaoming
Author: Benjamin Bach
Author-email: benjamin@overtag.dk
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires:
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling urllib2 and requests.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have two different Python environments. Scrapy seems to live in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy` while your urllib2 lives in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

Comment: Sorry im new to this. How would i fix this? Thanks.

Comment: @user4437880, install brew (from brew.sh website) and do a `brew install python`